# My Regex.Split with '\n' takes up two spaces instead of 1

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

I need to split my text into each word, space, and new line.
Although the words and spaces are properly working, the \n is taking up two spaces only if it's not after a word.
Example: "\nTest\nword", here, the first \n takes up two spaces while the second one takes up one.

How would I write the proper regex?

**My code:**

```
string delimiterChars = "([ \r\n])";
wordArray = Regex.Split(myTexy, delimiterChars);
```

For context, I am using Unity.

Input: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1qXO.png)

Output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJe6V.png)

On the output of the picture: The first element is empty and the second is \n here. I don't want the empty element.

Comment: Try repeating the character class `[ \r\n]+`

Comment: This is because in some systems, `\n` is actually shorthand for the two-character `\r\n` combo.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Split` will always produce empty items where the matches are consecutive, or when they are at the start/end of string.

Instead, you can use a matching and extracting approach:

```cs
string delimiterChars = "[^ \r\n]+|[ \r\n]";
string[] wordArray = Regex.Matches(myTexy, delimiterChars)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToArray();
```

The `[^ \r\n]+|[ \r\n]` regex matches one or more chars other than a space, CR and LF, or a space, CR or an LF char.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
string myStr = "This is test text";
            wordArray = myStr.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work. I need the spaces and \n to take up an array index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to remove leading delimiter characters.

```
    var myTexy = "\nTest\nword";
    string delimiterChars = "([ \r\n])";
    myTexy = Regex.Replace(myTexy, "^" + delimiterChars, "");
    var wordArray = Regex.Split(myTexy, delimiterChars);
```

The "^" regex option says only look for these characters at the beginning of the string.

Also, just so you are aware the behavior you are seeing is intended and is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-6.0):

> If a match is found at the beginning or the end of the input string,
> an empty string is included at the beginning or the end of the
> returned array.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for -

String text = "\nTest\nword";
string[] words = Regex.Split(text, @"(\n+)");

Output -
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't fit my scenario either. The first element is a problem and multiple newlines + spaces won't work in this case.  I think my English proficiency is causing issues. I need the spaces and newlines to take up exactly one array element regardless of where they are.